# Filling 2 different values for missing/NaN columns

Tags: data-cleaning, preprocessing, missing-data, data-analysis, data-imputation

I am doing a binary classification problem (`TARGET` = `0` or `1`). My dataset contains some NaN values in 6-7 columns. 
I want to fill those NaN with `mode()` / `most_frequent()` of each column. But it should be filled with two different values depending on the target. 
So, `NaN` for all those with `Target=1`; `mode()` of values with `Target=1` should be filled and similarly, for all those with `Target=0`; `mode()` for of values with `Target=0`.

I've tried the following code:

```
train_df[train_df.TARGET==1].fillna(train_df[train_df.TARGET==0].mode(),inplace=True)
```

and

```
train_df[train_df.TARGET==0]=train_df[train_df.TARGET==0].fillna(train_df[train_df.TARGET==0].mode())
```

Both of these codes didn't worked. I was still left with the same amount of `NaN` values.

But, when I run this-
    train_df[train_df.TARGET==0].fillna(train_df[train_df.TARGET==0].mode()).isnull().sum()

I observed all the missing values do get filled where `Target=0`.

Sometimes, I get this Warning:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:6287: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self._update_inplace(new_data)
```

I'm stuck at this for a long time and don't know how to proceed. Please suggest some solution to this.

Thanks

Comment: what's wrong with this ? `train_df.fillna(train_df[train_df.TARGET==0].mode(),inplace=True)`

Comment: I don't know. Even after running this, I have the same amount of missing values.

Comment: `train_df.fillna(train_df[train_df.TARGET==0].mode()).isnull().sum()` ?

Comment: yeah...when I run this...the count decreases...so the missing values did get replaced but it just happens in the copy and not on the dataset. I tried equating it to the variable to the dataset variable, but no good.